# R: regex from string to two dimensional data frame in one command?

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, sapply, strsplit

I have a string s containing such key-value pairs, and I would like to construct from it data frame,

```
s="{'#JJ': 121, '#NN': 938, '#DT': 184, '#VB': 338, '#RB': 52}"
r1<-sapply(strsplit(s, "[^0-9_]+",as.numeric),as.numeric)
r2<-sapply(strsplit(s, "[^A-Z]+",as.numeric),as.character)
d<-data.frame(id=r2,value=r1)
```

what gives:

```
r1
     [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]  121
[3,]  938
[4,]  184
[5,]  338
[6,]   52
 r2
     [,1]
[1,] ""  
[2,] "JJ"
[3,] "NN"
[4,] "DT"
[5,] "VB"
[6,] "RB"

 d
  id value
1       NA
2 JJ   121
3 NN   938
4 DT   184
5 VB   338
6 RB    52
```

First **I would like don't have NA and "" after using regular expression**. I think it should be something like {2,} meaning match all from second occurence, but I can not do that in R.

Another think I would like to do will be: having a data frame with column like below:

```
                                                              m
1   {'#JJ': 121, '#NN': 938, '#DT': 184, '#VB': 338, '#RB': 52}
2       {'#NN': 168, '#DT': 59, '#VB': 71, '#RB': 5, '#JJ': 35}
3      {'#JJ': 18, '#NN': 100, '#DT': 23, '#VB': 52, '#RB': 11}
4      {'#NN': 156, '#JJ': 39, '#DT': 46, '#VB': 67, '#RB': 21}
5       {'#NN': 112, '#DT': 39, '#VB': 57, '#RB': 8, '#JJ': 32}
6  {'#DT': 236, '#NN': 897, '#VB': 420, '#RB': 122, '#JJ': 240}
7     {'#NN': 316, '#RB': 25, '#DT': 66, '#VB': 112, '#JJ': 81}
8      {'#NN': 198, '#DT': 29, '#VB': 85, '#RB': 37, '#JJ': 44}
9                                                   {'#RB': 30}
10     {'#NN': 373, '#DT': 48, '#VB': 71, '#RB': 21, '#JJ': 36}
11       {'#NN': 49, '#DT': 17, '#VB': 23, '#RB': 11, '#JJ': 8}
12  {'#NN': 807, '#JJ': 135, '#DT': 177, '#VB': 315, '#RB': 69}
```

I would like to iterate over each row and split it numerical values into the columns named by the key.

Example of few rows showing, how I would like it will looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would want the output of the second part of your question to look like.

Comment: @AnandaMahto The table in the picture shows what I would like to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use something that parses JSON, what your data seems to be:

```
s <- "{'#JJ': 121, '#NN': 938, '#DT': 184, '#VB': 338, '#RB': 52}"

parse.one <- function(s) {
  require(rjson)
  v <- fromJSON(gsub("'", '"', s))
  data.frame(id = gsub("#", "", names(v)),
             value = unlist(v, use.names = FALSE))  
}

parse.one(s)
#   id value
# 1 JJ   121
# 2 NN   938
# 3 DT   184
# 4 VB   338
# 5 RB    52
```

For the second part of the question, I would pass a slightly modified version of the `parse.one` function through `lapply`, then let plyr's `rbind.fill` function align the pieces together while filling missing values with `NA`:

```
df <- data.frame(m = c(
  "{'#JJ': 121, '#NN': 938, '#DT': 184, '#VB': 338, '#RB': 52}",
  "{'#NN': 168, '#DT': 59, '#VB': 71, '#RB': 5, '#JJ': 35}",
  "{'#JJ': 18, '#NN': 100, '#DT': 23, '#VB': 52, '#RB': 11}",
  "{'#JJ': 12, '#VB': 5}"
))

parse.one <- function(s) {
  require(rjson)
  y <- fromJSON(gsub("'", '"', s))
  names(y) <- gsub("#", "", names(y))
  as.data.frame(y)
}

library(plyr)
rbind.fill(lapply(df$m, parse.one))
#    JJ  NN  DT  VB RB
# 1 121 938 184 338 52
# 2  35 168  59  71  5
# 3  18 100  23  52 11
# 4  12  NA  NA   5 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

For now, I'll offer a solution to the first part of your question. Clean up your string and use `read.table`:

```
s="{'#JJ': 121, '#NN': 938, '#DT': 184, '#VB': 338, '#RB': 52}"
read.table(text = gsub(",", "\n", gsub("[{|}|#]", "", s)), 
           header = FALSE, sep = ":", strip.white=TRUE)
#   V1  V2
# 1 JJ 121
# 2 NN 938
# 3 DT 184
# 4 VB 338
# 5 RB  52
```

---

For the second part, here's another alternative using `concat.split` from a package I wrote called "splitstackshape":

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(m = c(
  "{'#JJ': 121, '#NN': 938, '#DT': 184, '#VB': 338, '#RB': 52}",
  "{'#NN': 168, '#DT': 59, '#VB': 71, '#RB': 5, '#JJ': 35}",
  "{'#JJ': 18, '#NN': 100, '#DT': 23, '#VB': 52, '#RB': 11}"
))
```

Similar cleanup as above, plus add an "id" column.

```
df$m <- gsub("[{|}|#]", "", df$m)
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
```

Load the "splitstackshape" package:

```
# install.packages("splitstackshape")
library(splitstackshape)
df2 <- concat.split(concat.split.multiple(df, "m", ",", "long"), 
                    "m", ":", drop = TRUE)
## df2 <- df2[complete.cases(df2), ] ## 
## ^^ might be necessary if there are NAs in the resulting data.frame
```

The data are now in a "long" format that is easy to manipulate:

```
df2
#    id time m_1 m_2
# 1   1    1  JJ 121
# 2   2    1  NN 168
# 3   3    1  JJ  18
# 4   1    2  NN 938
# 5   2    2  DT  59
# 6   3    2  NN 100
# 7   1    3  DT 184
# 8   2    3  VB  71
# 9   3    3  DT  23
# 10  1    4  VB 338
# 11  2    4  RB   5
# 12  3    4  VB  52
# 13  1    5  RB  52
# 14  2    5  JJ  35
# 15  3    5  RB  11
```

Here's an example of manipulating the data, using `dcast` from the "reshape2" package:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df2, id ~ m_1, value.var="m_2")
#   id  DT  JJ  NN RB  VB
# 1  1 184 121 938 52 338
# 2  2  59  35 168  5  71
# 3  3  23  18 100 11  52
```